# How to use javascript variables in forms in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the css property of the div through a click event.

I want to use saved properties in the input form.

I have already created a color column in the database, and I want to know how to apply a var color declared in Javascript to a partial view (_form.html.erb).

**index.html.erb (home controller)**

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/form', locals: { post: @post } %>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".scale-up-center").click(function() {
            var color = $(".scale-up-center").css("background-color");
            $(".first_scale").css("background-color", color);
        })
    })

<div class=".scale-up-center", style="background-color:red;"></div>
<div class=".first_scale"></div>
```

**_form.html.erb (Posts Controller)**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :color %>
    <%= form.text_area :color %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to set `text_area: color` value, equivalent to color value which you got in `var color` in javascript?

Comment: That's what I want !

Comment: I just tried and commented on the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_form.html.erb (Posts Controller)

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :color %>
    <%= form.text_area :color, id: 'post_color' %>
  </div>
```

Set Color value using javascript on click function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".scale-up-center").click(function() {
            var color = $(".scale-up-center").css("background-color");
            $(".first_scale").css("background-color", color);
            //set post's color value
            $("#post_color").val(color); 
        })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the correct answer.
But can not we get the css property name itself like red, yellow instead of rgb()?

Comment: @yori We can, but it can be done by some extra javascript or any third party jquery plugin, rather i would suggest you to use hex code instead or color name.

Comment: I want to get the color value and save it to the DB via form. My column in the DB does not understand rgb ().

Comment: @yori Your column should be string type and i think you can store any value in string type column. to make it understandable at view layer you would need any jquery plugin, but as far as concern to save value to string in string type column or text type column it can definitely be saved.

Comment: I have not passed validation when submitting rgb via form.

Can you give me a hint that I can not find the answer when I search?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you want to render the input box with a colour stored in your database? In that case you could style the element you want using

```
<div style="background: <%= model.colour_field %>;">
```

Comment: Currently I am saving the css property to color when I click .scale-up-center, and am modifying the background-color of .first_scale.

And I'm looking for a way to pass the properties stored in color to the text_area of ​​the partial view (_form.html.erb) as an argument.

Comment: In that case what @Gabbar has done should work for you